# Convert each value in the array to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array

```
var p = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

and I want to convert each value in the array to string like

```
var p = ['0','1','2','3','4'];
```

any ideas, help please?

Comment: why give me a negative? drop me a comment at least.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert number to string simply by prepending empty string to it.

```
p = p.map(function(e){return ""+e});
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is pass the Number value to the String function to get a string out of a Number.

```
[0,1,2,3,4].map(function(value) { return String(value); });
```

Comment: would this cause error if the given value is already on string?

Comment: No It wouldn't cause an error. You can pass anything to the String function